# Multiple timestamp values for training data

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, audio-recognition

I am trying to extract features from audio WAV-files with the [openl3](https://github.com/marl/openl3) package. It is working so far, but since openl3 works with windows, I have now for each WAV-file two numpy files, one with the embeddings (feature values) and one with the timestamp values.

For example the output for one WAV-file with 3 windows/timestamps looks like this:

timestamps:

```
[0. 1. 2.]
```

embeddings (with each list 6144 values/features long):

```
[[ 2.430837    1.1149534   1.8192575  ... -0.42393693  2.429424
   2.069307  ]

 [ 1.8306035   0.93579465  2.0597208  ... -0.41671506  2.2733474
   1.8177178 ]

 [ 4.8046613   1.4510491   3.1910005  ... -0.3726427   2.195802
   0.5922224 ]]
```

Now I have not figured out yet how to pass these values correctly to a ML-model as training data. I have looked into time series, but I am not really sure, if that is the correct way here, since the time series is technically the WAV-file itself and the openl3-tool has already extracted the features from it.

I have found another [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371065/how-to-use-time-series-data-in-classification-in-sklearn) to just concatenate all (in this case) 3 lists and pass as data, but since the WAV-files are of different length, they also have a different number of timestamps/windows and therefore more or less 'embedding lists'

So I do not think it would work to simply concatenate the lists or am I wrong here?
If someone could point me in the right direction, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is it that you want to classify? What kind of model do you wish to use for classifying?

Comment: The time-stamps are normally not used in the classifier, only the embeddings vector.